# Locus where morphism has positive-dimensional fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{A}^n\to\mathbb{A}^n$ be a dominant morphism of degree $d$. Then there exists a subvariety $Y\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$ such that the fibre of $f$ over $y$ is a zero-dimensional subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^n$ of degree $d$ (i.e. consists of $d$ points counted with multiplicity) as long as $y\notin Y$.

It seems intuitively clear that the degree of this exceptional variety $Y$ should be bounded in terms of $d$. Can someone provide me a reference that implies this fact?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f:\mathbb A^n\to\mathbb A^n$ defined by $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (y_1=x_1^d,y_2=x_2,\dots,y_n=x_n)$. Then depending on how you want to define $Y$, it is either empty or
$Y=(y_1=0)$ which is a hyperplane, i.e., degree $1$ in $\mathbb A^n$. In either case the degree of $Y$ is independent of $d$.

Another example, just in case: $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1^dx_2,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. In this case, the set $(y_2=0)\setminus (y_1=0)$ is not in the image and the fibers over the set $(y_1=y_2=0)$ are not zero-dimensional, so I suppose in this case $Y$ is the union of those sets, which is $(y_2=0)$, again of degree $1$ and independent of $d$. Unless you want to include the locus where the fibers are zero-dimensional but non-reduced in which case you'd have to add $(y_1=0)$ to $Y$, but then the degree is still only $2$ and still independent of $d$.

---

Re: comment

Indeed, I misunderstood your question. But I think the answer is still no.

Here is another example. Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb A^{n-1}$ be a hypersurface, defined by the equation $g(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})=0$ and consider the morphism, $f:\mathbb A^n\to\mathbb A^n$ given by $y_i=x_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$ and $y_n=x_ng(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$. Then if $y\in Y$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is infinite and $f$ is an isomorphism over $\mathbb A^n\setminus Y$, so $\deg f=1$ and $\deg Y$ is arbitrary. If one composes this morphism with the first morphism above, then one can obtain an $f$ with degree $d$ and still $\deg Y$ being arbitrary.

Comment: Regarding $k=d$, you are absolutely right and I edited my question accordingly.  But there seems to be some misunderstanding implicit in the rest of your answer: I do not see how the examples you gave contradict my statement. I ask for the degree of $Y$ to be bounded in terms of $d$ (i.e. I would like to have $\mathrm{deg}(Y)=O_d(1)$). You gave examples where $\deg(Y)\leq 2$, which certainly does not contradict the above.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I thought you meant a lower bound. (Perhaps you should try to be clear on what you are asking.) I added another example that should show that this is still not happening. Cheers.